# Cannot debug in VS2015 in specific project

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have a project which is Web application and use .Net Framework 4.5. I can debug some projects in VS2015, but some project I am unable to debug. I checked the web.config and it shows it can be debug. It should not be Firewall issue because the other web application can debug. I searched the web and tried many methods and didn't solve.  Would someone tell me how to solve.

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

There is an error message:

[image]

There is my property

[image]

Comment: If you look in the system tray of Windows (lower right corner) can you find an icon for IIS Express?  Clicking on the icon, do you see a website running at the port 53666 shown in your screenshot?

Comment: @EricJ. I cannot see the IIS Express in the system tray of Windows.

Comment: After changing Local IIS to IIS Express then clicking "create Virtual Directory", I can debug. However I need to do it every time I opened my project